# add margin to table header

Tags: html, css

On [this page](http://www.iol.ie/~murtaghd/stef/service.html) I would like to add a white gap between the background of the "Before" and "After table headings, that aligns with the gap between the photos in each column

[image]

I've tried setting the `width`, `max-width` and `margin-right` properties of the "Before" heading and also tried setting the `margin-left` of the "After" heading, but none of these seem to work.

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is using colgroup and set a border to act as margin.

```
<table>
    <colgroup />
    <colgroup style="border-left:5px solid #fff;" />
```

See also: http://jsfiddle.net/gwYaQ/

A table is easiest I admit, but it's not really tabular data is it.
You're abusing the table for layout =P

Info about colgroup: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_colgroup.asp

Comment: I think it's a borderline case of "abusing the table for layout". I mean, semantically, I think my <tr> elements really are rows, the headings really are table headings etc. Just because it's not a list of numbers doesn't mean it's not a table :)

Comment: Borderline true, in any case, table cells do not support individual margins. A table only allows uniform margins over all it's children so you either have to resort to creative usage of borders or even more creative usage of margins along with more divs to get the desired representation.

Comment: I meant "creative usage of paddings" in the above comment... not margins since table cells do not support individual margins...

Answer (score 1):

There's a rather dirty way, but does the job:

```
<tr>
    <th>Before</th>
    <th style="width: 10px; background: none;">&nbsp;</th>
    <th>After</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>IMG1</td>
    <td>&nbps;</td>
    <td>IMG2</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve that simply changing your CSS.

The white gap between the photo is due to the table cells padding-right (10px), so it's "inside" the cell.

The gradient in the heading being the backgound of the heading cells, a white space between them would have to be "ouside".

On way to fix this would be to add a 10px wide column between the 2 columns. Another is to use colgroup.

But BGerrissen is right : you should not use  for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
th {
    padding-left: 50px;
}

td {
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.